# Can't get the intended data with google place api

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

## Problem

I tried to get the data of the review and the phone number with the following url, but most of the values ​​except the `text` and `rating` of the phone number and the review are nil. .. However, if you hit the url directly on the web, you can check the intended json data.
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="PLACE ID"&fields=reviews,formatted_phone_number&key="api key"`

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) says if available. at the end of the description of the missing data. What does this mean? I don't know what it means.

I think there are no grammatical mistakes because there is data that can be obtained.
In addition, since the Model generated the data confirmed by hitting the api directly using [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/), it is hard to think of a typo.

```
struct Empty: Codable {
    let result: Result
    let status: String?
}

// MARK:-Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let formattedPhoneNumber: String?
    let reviews: [Review]
}

// MARK:-Review
struct Review: Codable {
    let authorName: String?
    let authorurl: String?
    let language: String?
    let profilePhotourl: String?
    let rating: Int?
    let relativeTimeDescription, text: String?
    let time: Int?
}
```

jsonData (I'm wondering if I can show the data as it is, so I'm replacing the actual data with x)

```
{
   "html_attributions" :[],
   "result" :{
      "formatted_phone_number": "xx-xxxx-xxxx",
      "reviews" :[
         {
            "author_name" :"xxxx",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/reviews",
            "language" :"xx",
            "profile_photo_url" :"https://xxxxx.com/-xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "rating" :4
            "relative_time_description": "x months ago",
            "text": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.",
            "time": 1234567
         },
         {
            "author_name": "xxxxxxxx",
            "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/xxxxxxxx/reviews",
            "language" :"xx",
            "profile_photo_url" :"https://lh6.ggpht.com/-xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "rating" :5
            "relative_time_description": "x weeks ago",
            "text": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "time": 1234567
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Server response is in snake case so you need to set the decoder key encoding strategy before you decode the json. Something like this

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```